# Yii2, ActiveQuery search model if there are existing relation models

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

There are 2 Active Record models Questions(**Q**) and Answers(**A**).

For simplicity I omit unsignificant attributes:

- **Q**: question_id
- **A**: answer_id, question_id

**Q** hasMany **A**, link by question_id

```
public function getAnswers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::className(), ['question_id' => 'question_id']);
}
```

How can I create find query for finding only **Q** models, which have at least one related **A** model?

This query require in ActiveDataProvider in basic **Q** Search model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerJoinWith` ([doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#innerJoinWith()-detail)):

```
Q::find()->innerJoinWith(['answers'])->all();
```

Comment: Thank you @vitalik_74, it works. For ActiveDataProvider query must be without `->all()`